# Running jsf 2.2 on jboss eap 6.0

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, cdi

When I am trying to update the jboss 6.0 eap to work with jsf 2.2 i am getting the following error. I have updated the jars and the appropriate module.xml files in javax/faces/api/main and com/sun/jsf-impl/main to jsf-impl-2.2.4 and jsf-api-2.2.4.

```
15:54:11,888 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-5) Critical error during deployment: : org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:578) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.10.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.loadFlows(ApplicationAssociate.java:323) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:303) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108) [jsf-api-2.2.4.jar:2.2]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2163) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:296) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:288) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:691) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:253) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

 15:54:11,888 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/DWP]] (MSC service thread 1-5) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
 Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.builder.FlowDefinition
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:578) [weld-core-1.1.10.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.10.Final-redhat-1]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.loadFlows(ApplicationAssociate.java:323) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:303) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108) [jsf-api-2.2.4.jar:2.2]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2163) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:296) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:288) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:691) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:253) [jsf-impl-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
... 8 more

  15:54:11,888 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Error listenerStart
 15:54:11,888 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context [/DWP] startup failed due to previous errors
 15:54:11,904 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./DWP: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./DWP: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

Answer (score 0):

JBoss WELD container is not up to date to use JSF 2.2.

I upgraded the WELD modules in pretty much the same way JSF was upgraded using [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jsf/installing-jsf-22-on-jboss-as-7) and [that](http://marcusschiesser.de/2013/01/17/how-to-use-jsf-2-2-with-jboss-7-1/)

WELD was upgraded by adding new versions(slots) of the modules in

```
1. $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/weld/api,
2. $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/weld/core and
3. $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/weld/spi
```

Be careful to make backups of the current modules before making changes and also not to replace the "main" version(slot) but to create new slots(versions) instead.

Found on

1. [api](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-api/2.1.Final),
2. [core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-core/2.1.0.Final) and
3. [spi](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-spi/2.1.Final) respectively.

Notice the version chosen is 2.1, it was the highest common version at time of writing this.

For more on modules try going through [the official docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction).

Comment: I did that but i got the following error :  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.logging.messages.XmlMessage

Comment: @user19999111 I also tried and got the error you did. How did you resolve it?

Comment: Any updates? how did you resolve XMLMessage Exception? @user19999111

Answer (score 0):

I added the following in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
        <global-modules>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>
        </global-modules>
        ...
</subsystem>
```